# How to return JSON using node or Express

Tags: node.js, json, httpresponse

My http get request is returning [object][object]. How do I stringify my request so that it returns the data in proper json?

```
function httpGet() {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        var options = {
            host: 'api.airtable.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/v0/app000000000/Database?filterByFormula=(DrugName=%27azatadine%27)',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer key12345677890'
            }
        };
        const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
            response.setEncoding('utf8');
            let returnData = '';

            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
              returnData += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', () => {
              resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
            });

            response.on('error', (error) => {
              reject(error);
            });
          });
          request.end();   
    }));
}
```

I would like to return the Indication in a record such as the get response below:

```
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo",
            "fields": {
                "DrugName": "azatadine",
                "nameapi": [
                    "recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo"
                ],
                "Indication": "For the relief of the symptoms of upper respiratory mucosal congestion in perennial and allergic rhinitis, and for the relief of nasal congestion and eustachian t.b. congestion.",
                "lookup": [
                    "azatadine"
                ],
                "drugID": "recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo"
            },
            "createdTime": "2018-11-09T19:38:24.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Your code does `resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));` which attempts to parse the data you received and change if FROM JSON into a Javascript object.  So, if the code does what it is designed to do, this function returns a promse that resolves to a Javascript object, not JSON.  If you want JSON as the resolved value and the http request is retrieving JSON, then don't parse it before calling `resolve()`, just return the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out `JSON.parse` from `response.on('end')` callback and you should be good. Reason being `returnData` is JSON formatted, parsing it will return the JS object representation but what you want is the JSON string.